# Example for Camel, CDI and CXF SOAP

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, cdi

Do you know an example where camel, cdi and cxf soap services are combined? I found those: https://github.com/fabric8io/ipaas-quickstarts/tree/master/archetypes

But all cxf examples provide rest services instead of webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples are prepared from Camel itself:

- [CXF component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)
- [CXF examples](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-example.html)